# Lead function based on value change of column in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window

Is there an easy way to do this?

Basically, I want to find the first "next date" when my "flag_code" column change status (1 or 0).
If I have 3 same status consecutively, I want to track the same first date.

Thank u

`Input`

| id | flag_ code | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2022-10-01 |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-10-02 |
| 1 | 0 | 2022-10-03 |
| 1 | 0 | 2022-10-04 |
| 1 | 0 | 2022-11-20 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-02-01 |

`Desired Output`

| id | flag_ code | date | **next_date** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-10-02 |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-10-02 | 2022-10-03 |
| 1 | 0 | 2022-10-03 | 2023-02-01 |
| 1 | 0 | 2022-10-04 | 2023-02-01 |
| 1 | 0 | 2022-11-20 | 2023-02-01 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-02-01 | NULL |

---

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with a combination of window functions and then do a join to get the needed result:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    [1, 0, "2022-10-01"],
    [1, 1, "2022-10-02"],
    [1, 0, "2022-10-03"],
    [1, 0, "2022-10-04"],
    [1, 0, "2022-10-20"],
    [1, 1, "2023-02-01"],
]),
    ['id', 'flag_code', 'date'])

w = Window.orderBy("date")
df = df.withColumn("diff", when(col("flag_code") == lag("flag_code").over(w), 0).otherwise(1)) \
    .withColumn("sum", sum("diff").over(w)) \
    .withColumn("next_sum", col("sum") + 1)
df_min = df.groupby("sum").agg(min("date").alias("next_date"))
df = df.drop("sum").join(df_min, df.next_sum == df_min.sum, "left").select("id", "flag_code", "date", "next_date")
df.orderBy("date").show()
```

Result:

```
+---+---------+----------+----------+
| id|flag_code|      date| next_date|
+---+---------+----------+----------+
|  1|        0|2022-10-01|2022-10-02|
|  1|        1|2022-10-02|2022-10-03|
|  1|        0|2022-10-03|2023-02-01|
|  1|        0|2022-10-04|2023-02-01|
|  1|        0|2022-10-20|2023-02-01|
|  1|        1|2023-02-01|      null|
+---+---------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there another way to do this? For example using a "First" function on "Lag function"?

Comment: Using  "First" function on "Lag function" ? What do you mean exactly, lag and first functions can be applied on a window in apache spark, you cannot apply a First on a Lag, I'm not sure what do you mean exactly?